# Is EVM vulnerable to denial of service with out of gas in call to other contract?

Tags: out-of-gas, revert-opcode, vulnerability, denial-of-service

if I call a function in a sub-contract and it runs out of gas, the gas is not completely consumed. Instead, it is returned to the calling contract.
Could that be a vulnerability for a denial of service attack?

When calling the function *burn()* directly from the contract Burner, it costs 3000000 gas.

When calling the function *burn()* from the contract Caller via call(), it costs only 41935 gas.

This is even (12 times) cheaper than calling the function *makeRevert()* which costs 513115 gas while going through less loops.

```
    pragma solidity 0.8.6;


contract Caller{
    
    function callBurner(address _burnerAddress) public returns(bool){
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = _burnerAddress.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("burn()"));
        return success;
    }
}

contract Burner{
    uint256 public res;
    
    function burn() public{
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < 90000000; i++){ // runs out of gas
            res = i + 1;
        }
    }
    
    function makeRevert() public{
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            res = i + 2;
        }
        revert();
    }
}
```